# How to style p-header of p-dialog i.e the whole header part?

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

I am trying to style the p-header of primeng dialog box p-dialog component and am stuck at styling it. I want the whole header element to be red but instead just my text is getting red. Here is my code snippet:

Here is the result I am getting:

[image: Here is the result I am getting]

This is the desired output:

[image: This is the desired output]

```html
<p-dialog  [(visible)]="popup.visible">
  <p-header [ngStyle] = "{'background-color':'red'}">
    {{popup.header}}
  </p-header>
  {{popup.message}}
</p-dialog>
```

I have also tried `styleClass`, `ngClass` , `[style]` getting no luck also

```
 @Component({
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

works but I don't want to disable viewEncapsulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you don't have this classes in template from Primeng components, you can't access them from a template-component.css

For this situation you need a global/theme css file that overrides the styles from PrimeNG.

Or you can use **depricated** selector `::ng-deep` in component css file like this:

```
  :host ::ng-deep .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar {
      background-color: red;
  }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer even i already have a global style which i don't want to touch and ng-deep does not works for me.

Answer (score 3):

```
:host ::ng-deep .p-dialog .p-dialog-header{
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.